# Multiple login mappings for linked server

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

Can we assign two logins for two different databases on target server. 
For example, I would like to create a Linked Server between **ServerA** and **ServerB**.

ServerB has two databases on it and both using different logins to access. Say **DB1** has **Login1** and **DB2** has **Login2**

So can I create something like this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'db_link', @srvproduct=N'SQLServer OLEDB Provider', @provider=N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc=N'ServerB'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'db_link',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'Login',@rmtuser=N'Login1',@rmtpassword='Password1'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'db_link',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=N'login',@rmtuser=N'Login2',@rmtpassword='Password2'
```

Am I able to access two different databases using this same linked server. I tried but with no success. Is there any way around it?